# PySpark DataFrame filter using logical AND over list of conditions -- Numpy All Equivalent

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter rows of a PySpark dataframe if the values of all columns are zero.

I was hoping to use something like this, (using the numpy function `np.all()` ):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.filter(all([(col(c) != 0) for c in df.columns]))
```

But I get the ValueError:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Is there any way to perform the logical and on a list of conditions? What is the corresponding `np.all` functionality in PySpark?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just `reduce` the list of predicates

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from operator import and_
from functools import reduce

df.where(reduce(and_, (col(c) != 0 for c in df.columns)))
```

or

```
df.where(reduce(and_, (col(c) != 0 for c in df.columns), lit(True)))
```

if you expect that the list of predicates might be empty.

For example if data looks like this:

```py
df  = sc.parallelize([
    (0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0),  (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1)
]).toDF(["x", "y", "z"])
```

the result will be:

```
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: It is a tragedy that zero323 was forced from this site, as I would really like an explanation for how this works. Exactly what I needed

Comment: As far as I can see from my own tests, you don't even need the lit(True). It should work without

Comment: Here's a link to [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [and_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.and_) documentation.

Comment: In Python, keywords (like `and` and `or`) are all functions. We can call them with syntactic sugar (`True and False`) or use the function directly (`and_(True, False)`). `reduce` takes a 2-argument function and collection then cumulatively applies that function to items in the collection. Doing `reduce(and_, (1, 2, 3))` is equivalent to `((1 and 2) and 3)`. So if you have columns `["a", "b", "c"]`, then Zero's code returns `((col("a") and col("b")) and col("c"))`.

Comment: The last argument of `reduce` is the initializer, used when the collection is empty. `reduce(_and, [], True)` will produce `(True)`. If there's a chance your collection is empty, use the initializer. Zero is saying: if I have no columns, use this Column containing True. Here's documentation on [lit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lit.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit).